# WordPress How to output next post and previous post with custom name?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using twenty twelve theme ,and i am trying to output Next post and Previous Post at the bottom of inner page.

The thing is this function  outputs the post title and 2 arrows like this :
**Remaining essentially unchanged »**

```
        <?php next_post_link(); ?>
```

What I am trying to achieve is to have only  **< Previous Post  -  Next Post >**.

Can anyone help me out with this one ?

Thank you.

Comment: Why not change it in the language file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a formater and link text arguments to your code.

```
previous_post_link( '< %link', 'Previous Post');
next_post_link( '%link >', 'Next Post');
```

Something like that should work for you.

Comment: yes it worked ,Thanks a lot , another thing , insted of < > i want to add some circle img's , can it be added inside the function ? or with CSS :after , :before ? i want the  <  > arrows to be the links and the Prev Next to be just Text . Thank you .

Comment: You can add whatever HTML you want to the code. just make sure that %link is in the first argument somewhere. `next_post_link('<i class="fa fa-whatever"></i> %link'...`

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the link text by passing it as the second parameter.

```
<?php next_post_link( '%link', 'Link Text Here' ); ?>
```

So in your case, your next link would be

```
<?php next_post_link( '%link', 'Next Post >' ); ?>
```

You can do the same with prev_post_link().

Further reading: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link

Comment: Been reading that ,i just coudnt understand it that good , i am new . Thanks

Comment: No problem, glad to help!